# Page Pagination/Scraping with Requests/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

[Scraper to get all links from news archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMi8Y.jpg)

In theory, this should work but it is not iterating over all the pages it only gets links from page 1. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement is inside the while loop, so it is called on the first iteration of the loop.

It should be outdented to the same level as the while.